# Cannot visualize percentage numbers (getting NaN)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Does anyone have any idea why I cannot generate percentage in the following 
[codeIshere](https://jsfiddle.net/3860zcc3/11/) (lines 97-117)?

```
var format=d3.format(".1%");

var percent = format(function(d){
                    if (d[values[0]]>d[values[1]]) {return (d[values[0]]-d[values[1]])/d[values[0]];}
                    else {return (d[values[1]]-d[values[0]])/d[values[1]];}});

bar1.append("text")
.attr("class", "label")
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.id) + 16; })
.attr("y",  function(d) {
                if (d[values[0]] > d[values[1]]) {return y(d[values[0]]) - 35;}
                else {return y(d[values[1]]) - 35;}})
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.style("fill", function(d) {
                if (d[values[0]] > d[values[1]]) {return "green";}
                else {return "red";}})
.text(function(d){
        if (d[values[0]]>d[values[1]]) {return "-" + percent;}
        else {return  percent;}});
```

I have been playing with it the whole morning and I'm out of ideas. I couldn't find the answer in the other posts.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: NaN could be the result of this op: 0/0. Maybe this helps you tracking down the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working code: https://jsfiddle.net/3860zcc3/15/

According to the formatting documentation

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting

> "In addition to numbers, D3 also supports formatting and parsing dates, and comma-separated values."

If you replace

```
var percent = format(function(d){
                        if (d[values[0]]>d[values[1]]) {return (d[values[0]]-d[values[1]])/d[values[0]];}
                        else {return (d[values[1]]-d[values[0]])/d[values[1]];}}
```

with a number like

```
var percent = format(2);
```

formatting works.

But even a simple function like:

```
var percent = format(function(d){return 2;});
```

is not working.

My guess is a function is not supported. So I took your code inside another function and returned that result inside the fiddle.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to compute the percentage in the .text(function(d){}) function. (This code may probably be made a bit shorter.)

```
 .text(function(d){
    var percent;
        if (d[values[0]]>d[values[1]])
        {
           percent = (d[values[0]]-d[values[1]])/d[values[0]];
        }
        else 
        {
          percent = (d[values[1]]-d[values[0]])/d[values[1]];
        }

        if (d[values[0]]>d[values[1]]) {return "-" + percent;}
        else {return  percent;}});
;
```